# Aggregate data when dealing with both continuous and categorical data

Tags: python, group-by, aggregate

I have the following data:

[image]

There are six customers who took out loans multiple times offered by Agents. Agents serve multiple customers. For example Agent 306 provided loans to Customer 1 and 2. Similarly, Agent 309 provided loans to Customer 5 and 6. I would like to aggregate the amount of loans each customer took and get something like in the table below. It is important I see the gender of the customer and agent after aggregation.

[image]

I tried the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Customer_ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6],
      'Loan': [200, 250, 300, 400, 300, 500, 150, 150, 400, 250, 150, 300, 200, 200],
     'CustomerGender': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
     'Agent_ID': [306, 306, 306, 306, 306, 307, 308, 308, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309], 
     'AgentGender': ['F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M','M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
     'settlement_value': [23.5, 30.99, 306, 86, 50, 307.35, 1200.54, 25, 48.88, 400, 2100.10, 30, 1309.10, 500.50]}

 
# transform to dataframe

data = pd.DataFrame(data)


# declare the two gender columns categorical

data['AgentGender']=data['AgentGender'].astype('category')

data['CustomerGender']=data['CustomerGender'].astype('category')
 
# aggregate the data by Customer_ID to see the total amount of loan each customer took.

data.groupby(data['Customer_ID']).sum()
```

What I get is the following:

[image]

How can I aggregate by Customer_ID and be able to see the gender of customers and agents please? Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

choose all the columns you need within a groupby and sum Loan amount

```
df.groupby(['Customer_ID','Customer_Gender','Agent_ID', 'Agent_Gender'])['Loan'].sum().reset_index()
```

or
if you are converting the columns to categories, add observed=True parameter

```
df.groupby(['Customer_ID','Customer_Gender','Agent_ID', 'Agent_Gender'], observed=True)['Loan'].sum().reset_index()
```

```
    Customer_ID     Customer_Gender     Agent_ID    Agent_Gender    Loan
0   1                       M                306    F                750
1   2                       F                306    M                700
2   3                       M                307    M                500
3   4                       M                308    M                300
4   5                       F                309    F                1100
5   6                       F                309    F                400
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why your code gives me an empty table. only the column names are returned.

Comment: I have now added the data as Dictionary. Thanks for helping.

Comment: it works now, thanks!!! Unfortunately it doesn't let me vote on your answer as my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work on my big data which has around 500,000 rows. :-( It returns the same dataframe with the ordered Customer_IDs. What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: If solution works in sample but fails on large data then either the sample data is not representative like number of columns are different, or the data has some nuances like spaces in some values. 

Btw, solution I posted, the result from groupby is not assigned so could it be it that you’re referring to data frame and not the result of the group by?

Comment: @AndreaErőss, did you try the second of the two solutions? Second one has observed attribute in it. Can you try that too and advise?

Comment: It seems grouping works for categorical variables only. Customer_ID, Customer_Gender, Agent_Gender, Agent_ID are all categorical variables.  I have to add other variables that are continuous to the grouping; variables such as accounts_opened, settlement_value, write-off_amount. If I add these, grouping does not work. So I should have added to my example a continuous variable too. Thanks for trying to solve this for me. I can change the data if you think it would help.

Comment: I now added settlement_value as a continuous variable.

Comment: My apologies. applied the solution to the data you shared and result was as per your expectation. There is a gap in my understanding it seems which Im unable to figure out

Comment: thanks Naveed, you've been very helpful. I added a new column called 'settlement_value' to the dictionary called data. with this added column grouping doesn't work. I restarted Anaconda in case that was causing the issue. Adding this continuous variable, grouping does not work...